# Ceaser Cipher returning wrong output

Tags: javascript

Its suppose to give "FREE LOVE!" but instead returning "FREE LOVEL".
Some other output are correct: Eg OutPut ::("SERR CVMMN!") and ("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK.")

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var result = [];
  var a = str.split(" ");

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var b = a[i].split("");
    result[i] = b;
  }
  //return result;
  //var result2 = [ ];
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
      result[i][j] = result[i][j].charCodeAt() + 13;
      if (result[i][j] < 65) {
        result[i][j] = result[i][j] - 13; //'?' should revert back to 63***emphasized text*
      }
      //else if(result[i][j] == )
      else if (result[i][j] > 90) {
        result[i][j] = result[i][j] - 26;
      }

    }

  }
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
      result[i][j] = String.fromCharCode(result[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var d = result[i];
    var c = d.join("");
    result[i] = c;
  }
  //return result;
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result = result.join(" ");
    return result;
  }
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(rot13("SERR YBIR?"));
console.log(rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK."))
```

Comment: "_//'?' should revert back to 63_" If it would get in the if branch then yes but `63 + 13` is bigger than `65` and less than `90`

Comment: @Andreas Got it.   `    if(result[i][j] < 77)`has resolved the issue.